# Get the Site Path of a Component by Name - Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla 2.5 site. I have `JShopping` installed in that site. What I am doing that I have to create a CronJob for that site which is placed like `www.site.com/cron.php`

```
define('JPATH_BASE', '../');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
// Path of Joomshopping site folder
define('JPATH_SITE_JOOMSHOPPING', __DIR__."TODO");
// Date Varibale
/* Required Files */
require_once ( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
/* To use Joomla's Database Class */
require_once ( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'database' . DS . 'table.php' );
```

How to get the Site Path of that JoomShopping Component.(As I said its a CronJob, so in this file I am not executing any component though so `JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE` wont work for me).

**So how can I get path of a component by specifying its name only?**

Answer (score 2):

You can get the path of the current component like so:

```
echo JPATH_COMPONENT
```

For more information on Constants, have a read of the [Joomla Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Constants)

Hope this helps

### Update:

Try this:

```
JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_jshopping/';
```

Comment: Sorry but I have changed my question .. pls see it.

Comment: Please be clear in future as you what you require. See my updated answer